# AngularJS: Automatically select a radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I have two radio buttons and I want the first to be automatically selected

```
<input type="radio" name="playlist" ng-value="myCtrl.cleanPlaylist" ng-model="myCtrl.playlistSelected"> Clean

<input type="radio" name="playlist" ng-value="myCtrl.explicitPlaylist" ng-model="myCtrl.playlistSelected" ng-disabled="myCtrl.
```

I have the first one to be selected in my controller but for some reason it's not working...

```
var myModule = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller('MyController', function(){

this.explicitDisabled = false;

this.playlistSelected = this.cleanPlaylist;

})
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing someone but why not just add the `checked` property to the first? Couldn't believe the other answers didn't say that

Answer (score 2):

You must set a value for radio button, `ng-value` is an angular expression to which `ng-model` will be be set when the radio is selected, according to 
[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).

Then, to make it works you can do it as following:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
      var vm = this;
      
      vm.playlistSelected = 'clean';
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <input type="radio" name="playlist" value="clean" ng-model="main.playlistSelected"> Clean
  <input type="radio" name="playlist" value="complete" ng-model="main.playlistSelected"> Complete
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

playlistSelected is null, it will need a value that matches the value of the radio button. What is cleanPlaylist? Why not just hardcode the value of the radio and then set the playlistSelected to that value in the controller.